# How to keep command-line app running for Timer?

Tags: swift

Is there any way to keep an app running while the user doesn't kill the app? I found that this can be accomplished with `RunLoop.current.run()` but when hit the app in this like the app completely freezes. I've a Timer that is declared before the **RunLoop** and it seems to be correctly initialized but the timer doesn't process. Here's a simple example:

```
import Foundation

print("start")

let _ = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
    print("proc")
}

RunLoop.current.run()

print("end")
```

Seems that I'm not catching how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is merely that you don't know how to use a Timer. It isn't enough to `init` it. You have to *schedule* it. Instead of calling `init...`, call `Timer.scheduledTimer...` and the whole thing will spring to life for you. Then you'll see that in fact your process *is* running.

I put this (I can't use a block-based Timer because I'm not using Sierra) and it worked fine:

import Foundation

```
class TimerHolder:NSObject {
    var timer : Timer?
    @objc func timerFired(_:Timer) { print("fired") }
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, 
            selector: #selector(timerFired), 
            userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

print("start")

_ = TimerHolder()

RunLoop.current.run()

print("end")
```

Comment: thanks! my bad, long time without using timers... 

Comment: Even without the timer as a test, `"end"` never prints, so you can see that your command-line tool _is_ still running.